# How to get total sales of items per categories Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I try to figure out how to count total sales of items per categories of items.

`items` table:

```
+---------+--------------+----------------+
+ id      +  item_name   +  item_category +
+---------+--------------+----------------+
+ 1       + Yeezy Boost  +  2             +
+ 2       + Nike Blabla  +  1             +
+ 3       + Bata blabla  +  8             +
+ 4       + Vans blabla  +  3             +
```

`categories` table:

```
+---------+---------------+----------------------+
+ id      + category_name + category_description +
+---------+---------------+----------------------
+ 2       + Adidas        + Adidas category blab +
+ 1       + Nike          + Nike category blabla +
+ 8       + Bata          + Bata categor blabla  +
+ 3       + Vans          + Vans catyegory blaba +
```

`orders` table:

```
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+
+ id     + order_date + customer_id + status    +
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+
+ 1      + 2017-09-12 + 98          + shipped   +
+ 2      + 2017-08-22 + 87          + paid      +
+ 3      + 2017-07-31 + 33          + unpaid    +
+ 4      + 2017-09-14 + 12          + delivered +
+ 5      + 2016-09-22 + 90          + paid      +
```

`order_Details` table:

```
+-----+---------+-----------+
+ id  + item_id + orders_id +
+-----+---------+-----------+
+ 1   + 3       + 3         +
+ 2   + 4       + 3         +
+ 3   + 4       + 3         +
+ 4   + 1       + 2         +
+ 5   + 2       + 2         + 
+ 6   + 4       + 2         +
+ 7   + 3       + 2         +
+ 8   + 3       + 2         +
+ 9   + 1       + 5         +
+ 10  + 1       + 5         +
```

Well, I put the each order to `orders` table & the order details to `order_details` table, for example, if customer buy `3 items` with `id 1` in this case the item will be `Yeezy Boost` then this will insert `3 records` to `order_details` for each item, What I want is how to get how much items sold (get from `order_details` table) per categories, so in example table above, if I try to get items sold with category of 2 (Adidas) this will return 3 items. how to get this done, I'm using Laravel 5.4 I'll appreciate it for any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this sql script will help you to figure out total items saled on orders table.

```
SELECT i.id, i.item_name, count(i.id) total_items_saled   
FROM orders AS o
INNER JOIN order_details ON od.order_id = o.id
INNER JOIN items AS i ON i.id = od.item_id
INNER JOIN categories AS c ON c.id = i.item_category
GROUP BY c.id, i.id
WHERE o.status like 'paid'
```

Comment: I'll try it! Thanks!